# All line break removed in the server files

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress.
After upload my project file in the live server and then for any certain changes, I found everything inside "styles.css" files comes into only one line.

Even what ever inside the "header.php" or "footer.php" also comes into only one line.

Then its become hardest to search any particular keyword.

Can anybody please suggest me, how do I prevent this kinda editing in the server?
I am using "NetBean 7" as the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has converted your file types to match the server's file system it sounds like.  Your line breaks might be gone.  Try opening them in Notepad++ or vim to be sure.

If you look at it in Windows under Wordpad it should work too.

Comment: Netbeans also has a plugin to enable you to convert between Windows-style and non-Windows EOL types, which should help.

Comment: Yeah I was gonna mention that but if the files were already converted they probably lost the line break data too.